# Hierarchy of administrators in Liferay

Tags: liferay, user-management

What I need is:

- Administrator-level-1 (Can edit all simple users and administrators of level 2 and 3)
- Administrator-level-2 (Can edit all simple users and administrators of level 3)
- Administrator-level-3 (even less permissions)

By saying ***edit*** I mean ***change password*** at least. Tried to experiment with roles, permissions, Organization hierarchy etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an Organization for each level and then can create a single Organization Role with the following permissions:

1. User / Update
2. Organization / Manage Users
3. Organization / View

Once that is done you assign the level admins to this role on the corresponding organizations.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Although 4th permission (Manage Suborganizations) was necessary. Thank you. Any ideas why level 2 and 3 administrators don't see their organization (Control Panel->Portal-> Users and Organizations) under "My Organizations"? Their organization+suborganizations are listed only after pressing "Search All Organizations".

Comment: I guess they are not members, if the case is different I can fire up one of my LR instances to check :)

Comment: I believe they are members of suborganization. Even giving roles of Organization Owner/Administrator doesn't make organization appear under "My Organizations"